# Is there a way around doing 2000 else if statements in this?

Tags: android, arrays, if-statement, kotlin

I am creating a check in barcode app for my business in Android Studio. There are 2000 of these. A member types in their 6 digit membership number into `editText`, clicks Save, which triggers `saveToMain` below. My plan was to just use `else if` for each membership card. Kotlin doesn't like this and keeps crashing after about 200 of these. I'm very new to coding and literally learned the language just for this app, so I know approximately nothing, so, this might be crazy and there may be a much easier way. I've been searching on the Internet for the past two hours and can't seem to find anything with this same situation. You cannot use an array somehow for this, correct?

The `R.drawable.a0001` files below are the barcode images corresponding to their membership number.

```
fun alertDiag() {
    val alertDialog =
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
    alertDialog.setTitle("No Card Entered")
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please use 'Current Membership Card' for your previously saved Membership Card.")
    alertDialog.setButton(
        AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
        "OK"
    ) { dialog, which ->

    }

    alertDialog.show()
}


fun saveToMain(view: View) {
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
    val message = editText.text.toString()
    val image2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView2)

    if (message == "") {
        alertDiag() }
    else if (message == "100001") {image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0001);saveToStorage(view);goToGallery(view)}
    else if (message == "100002") {image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0002);saveToStorage(view);goToGallery(view)}
    else if (message == "100003") {image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0003);saveToStorage(view);goToGallery(view)}
    else if (message == "100004") {image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a0004);saveToStorage(view);goToGallery(view)}
    else {
        image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notfound)
    }
}
```

else if

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html

Comment: What's the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @Onik, thank you for your reply. All it does is go very slowly, until I try to copy and paste another 50 or so, and then it says something like Kotlin cannot save, and has been disabled, please restart the program.

Comment: @GSerg This looks to be what I need. How do I work this into what I have here? Would it be a tremendous amount of code? Do I just substitute the values and images for x and y?

Comment: You fill the map in a separate place with pairs of (`"100001", R.drawable.a0001`). In `saveToMain` you use the filled map to look up the resource id by `message`, without an `if`.

Comment: @GSerg But even that looks ugly and indicates unclear business requirements. Isn't there a deterministic (computable) relation between membership numbers and barcodes? I mean, that is the intent of barcodes is it not? They encode a number. I bet all conditional checks can be replaced with logic which renders a barcode based on a number.

Comment: I think a map is a mistake, because you're still filling it with 2000 manually checked/typed lines (unless you use reflection to generate the map entries or a script to generate the code). Ideally, this program would generate the barcode, but the OP may not have visibility to the algorithm for creating them.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Thank you for the suggestion! I believe I looked into this when I first started the brainstorming of how I could combat this, and my barcodes are unfortunately in Code128, not something common like UPC. There was something about it being proprietary, and something I would have to pay hundreds of dollars for. Since I will only ever need 2000 (my gym is on the smaller side, and even if I ever had 2000 members here it would be pushing it), I figured purchasing that from the owner of Code128 codes would be overkill.

Comment: @Tenfour04 That is correct. It is the algorithm to the barcodes that would cost money to purchase, and not something I'm looking to do. Is it the amount of lines that is making Kotlin disable, or is it the number of if statements? If I was filling the map and it wouldn't crash, I wouldn't mind doing it that way. It doesn't have to be pretty.

Comment: I don't know. It might be a bug in the compiler, or maybe Java simply can't handle more than a few hundred `if else` statements. I've been programming for about ten years and have never encountered any function that is more than a few dozen lines. Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function to retrieve a drawable's `Int` ID (the `R.drawable.whatever` values) using reflection.

```
fun findDrawableIdByName(name: String): Int? {
    return try {
        R.drawable::class.java.getField(name).getInt(null)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException){
        null
    }
}
```

Then assuming your message values are in a consecutive range, you could combine them all into one `else` block.

```
fun saveToMain(view: View) {
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
    val message = editText.text.toString()
    val image2 = findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView2)

    if (message == "") {
        alertDiag() 
    } else if (message.toIntOrNull() in 100001..102000) {
        val name = message.replaceRange(0, 2, "a") // replace the beginning 10 with "a"
        val drawableId = findDrawableIdByName(name)
        if (drawableId == null) {
            image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notfound)
        } else {
            image2.setBackgroundResource(drawableId)
            saveToStorage(view)
            goToGallery(view)
        }
    } else {
        image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notfound)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I was at this for HOURS when there was this simple, perfect solution. This works great. Thank you so so much. Where's your Paypal link for donations?

Comment: The only thing that doesn't work for some reason, is that it doesn't display the notfound image. But that's not a big deal. Small business, I can get away with things not being absolutely perfect.

Comment: Just kidding, all I had to do was add `saveToStorage(view); goToGallery(view)` to the end of the `image2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notfound)`. Perfect. Now I wonder if I can work this into the iOS app (Xcode did not crash when I did 2000 else ifs, but this is way prettier).