# Is there a way of writing this in XCode without 2000 if else statements?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, range

I'm writing a check in app for my gym in XCode. I asked this a year and a half ago for Android: [Is there a way around doing 2000 else if statements in this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303353/is-there-a-way-around-doing-2000-else-if-statements-in-this)

But now, I am reaching 2000 members and need to add more. Unfortunately, and obviously, Xcode is crashing when I try to add more lines.

My code is this:

```
    @IBAction func displayBarcode(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if nameTextField.text=="100001" {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("All Barcodes/a0001.jpg"));  
        }    
        else if nameTextField.text=="100002" { imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("All Barcodes/a0002.jpg"));}
        else if nameTextField.text=="100003" { imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("All Barcodes/a0003.jpg"));}
        else if nameTextField.text=="100004" { imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("All Barcodes/a0004.jpg"));}
        else if nameTextField.text=="100005" { imageView.image = UIImage(named: ("All Barcodes/a0005.jpg"));}
```

...all the way down to 2000. I know, absolutely crazy, but it has worked. Is there a way to combine these into one if/else statement into a range, similar to the solution someone gave me for Android?

Thank you sincerely!

Comment: I mean, I could rename the files to be exact, that wouldn't be an issue, but how to get that variable text field in the file name of the jpg is what I'm confused about and have been trying for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic solution to split the string and use part of it in the image name:

```
@IBAction func displayBarcode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let input = nameTextField.text else {
        return
    }
    guard input.count == 6, input.prefix(2) == "10" else {
        return
    }
    let imageName = "All Barcodes/a\(input.suffix(4)).jpg"
    if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

This does some *very* trivial validation (eg `count == 6` and it checks the prefix for `10`), which you could make more stringent if you needed it, but this works for the basic task.

Comment: No security concern really, it's a small business. I had an else at the end of all of that that displayed "no membership ID found". I would have never thought of (nor have I seen in my research) "input.suffix" but this was the solution I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Just get the last 4 digits, convert to integer, check if your desired range contains your value and check if they are all digits:

```
let string = "100002"
let suffix = string.suffix(4)
let range = 1...2000
if let int = Int(suffix),
    suffix.count == 4,
    suffix.allSatisfy(("0"..."9").contains),
    range ~= int {
    let imageName = "All Barcodes/a\(suffix).jpg"
    print(imageName)
}
```

---

This will print

> All Barcodes/a0002.jpg